# Cmake mingw error

Tags: windows, gcc, g++, cmake, mingw

I cam currently tyring to build CEGui for Ogre/mingw/eclipse/Windows/C++.

Cmake throws the first error (with a tons of further errors):

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 3.4.5
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
Check for working C compiler: D:/###/mingw/bin/gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: D:/###/mingw/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at D:/###/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "D:/###/mingw/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to
  compile a simple test program.
  It fails with the following output:
  Change Dir: D:/###/cegui-0.8.3_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
  Run Build Command:D:/###/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe
  "cmTryCompileExec1524602820/fast"

  D:/###/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
  CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec1524602820.dir\build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1524602820.dir/build
```

To be honest I am completely lost. Any clues how to fix that? Do I need any gcc compiler when working unter C++ at all? Are there any manual settings to Cmake to bypass this error?

Thank you for your help & kind regards,

Corak

Comment: I'm assuming you can compile a simple test program (eg. using commandline) with the c compiler - is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your C compiler is quite old, can you try a newer one (GCC 4.x)? You have libraries for GCC 3.x and GCC 4.x installed - those may be not compatible. Means: possible GCC 3.x uses GCC 4.x libraries and fail by this.

What version of CMake are you using? Please test with the latest version. You should also clear the CMake cache completely and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, ollo! I use CMake 2.8.2.12 and I am cleaning the cache, purging the source directory. A simple cropgram doens't compile as well :( I will try a newer version of GCC and post the result.

Comment: The new version did it! *happy* Thank you very much, ollo :) Now the error messages changed in a way very ogre/cegui-specific. I guess I first try out by myself and if I need further assistance open a new topic related to the leftover questions.

Comment: Just to understand you correct: It was the new version of *GCC* (not cmake) that solved the problem?

Comment: Dear ollo, the problem is solved, however, not in the intended way. I switched from eclipse/minGW to MSVS2010 - and from CEGui to MyGUI. Now everything works as intended (I just miss some of the eclipse-features) :)

Comment: I see, so please mark this question as *solved* by setting the *green tick* (accept the answer). Thanks.

Comment: Switching Compiler / IDE is a hard change - but nice to hear everything worked so good.